# Why are list items not filling the width of scrolled unordered list?

Tags: html, css

There have been a number of questions that dance around this, but not one that seems to nail the solution for me.

I have an unordered list with a set width, overflow-x so it can scroll horizontally, and its list items have white-space of no-wrap. The idea is that all list-items take up a single line, and the user can scroll horizontally if needed.

This all works, for the most part, but I'm finding that if items have a background-color, or some other styling, it becomes evident that the item itself doesn't fill the width of the ul's content area, to include its scrollable section.

Here's the demo:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
  </li>
    <li>
      This is short.
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like all list items to fill the scrollable width of the list. So in my demo, the red border for both items would extend all the way to the end.

Comment: Probably try creating an "overflow wrapper" for your `ul` that has the overflow property set and remove it from the `ul` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Create a div overflow wrapper with your width and overflow properties. Then set the `ul` to `display: inline-block` and you should get what you are after.

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
ul {     
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
  </li>
    <li>
      This is short.
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Without adding any additional markup you could try setting the `li`'s to `display: inline-block;` and maybe a `min-width: 100%;` to match the container's width (at least).

```css
ul {     
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
      This is very long.
  </li>
    <li>
      This is short.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oof. Thanks for the quick answer, and this does work. But my team's app has probably a hundred of these, and I was sort of hoping to find a CSS-only one-size-fits all. Having to wrap in a div is not the most ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately the update doesn't achieve my goal of having all list items the same width (same width as widest list item, essentially). Your original solution achieved the UI that I wanted, but adding markup was the issue.

Comment: Yeah, without additional markup might not be possible. You are wanting the sibling elements to be aware of each others overflowed content and determine the longest one, when they are only aware of the parents width. The overflowed stuffs is of unknown width. You would need javascript.